# Google maps marker clustering for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using Google maps plugin in my Reactjs application & I need to group markers basically need to use marker clustering like shown in attached Google maps marker clusters. [image]I didn't find any marker clustering library/plugin for React Google maps.

Can you please suggest any plugin for this? Or suggest a way to implement a custom plugin for this?

Comment: Did u try this npm library **npm i @react-google-maps/marker-clusterer** . If not let u pls try this. As well check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784252/how-to-add-clusters-with-google-map-react]

Comment: Hi, I tried but didn't get the cluster icon on the above mentioned type

Comment: While you try the above what error u was faced ? did u go through this [Example](https://github.com/Tim152/clustering-google-map-react)